# Php code inside array

Tags: php, html, twitter

How can i add the "for" function output inside the array? Thanks

```
for($idid = 0; $idid <= $say; $idid++) {
    echo "@";
    print_r($string[$idid]['screen_name']);
    echo " ";
}

$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json";
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$requestMethod = 'POST';
$response = $twitter->setPostfields(
    array(
        'status' => "I NEED TO ADD FOR FUNCTION OUTPUT HERE")
)
    ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
    ->performRequest();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should save to a variable instead of printing to screen like this:

```
$status = "";
for($idid = 0; $idid <= $say; $idid++) {
    $status .= "@";
    $status .= print_r($string[$idid]['screen_name'], true);
    $status .= " ";
}
```

The second parameter from `print_r` is to return the output instead for printing it. You can check more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)

And after that use the `$status` variable in your array like this:

```
$response = $twitter->setPostfields(
    array('status' => $status)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You would only need to build up a string while in your for-loop, then reference that in your API call:

```
$status = '';
for ($idid = 0; $idid <= $say; $idid++) {

    // Only keep if you're also printing output to the screen
    echo "@";
    print_r($string[$idid]['screen_name']);
    echo " ";

    // New Code
    $status .= '@' . $string[$idid]['screen_name'] . ' ';
}

$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json";
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$requestMethod = 'POST';
$response = $twitter->setPostfields(array(
        'status' => trim($status)
    ))->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
    ->performRequest();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of printing the strings, simply save them in a variable for later use.

```
$var = '';
for($idid = 0; $idid <= $say; $idid++) {
    $var = $var . "@";
    $var = $var . print_r($string[$idid]['screen_name'], true);
    $var = $var . " ";
}

...

$response = $twitter->setPostfields(
    array(
        'status' => $var)
)
```

Edit: print_r() accepts a second argument, if this is true the output is returned as a string instead of printed.

The period is used for string concatenation, and there are shortforms for this, i.e *$var .= ' ';* instead of *$var = $var . ' ';*. But for now I wrote the code explicit for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Make the contents from the for-loop a variable. Like this:

```
$output = "";
for($idid = 0; $idid <= $say; $idid++) {
    $output .= "@".print_r($string[$idid]['screen_name'], true)." "; // true makes it return the content instead of printing it
}

$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json";
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$requestMethod = 'POST';
$response = $twitter->setPostfields(
    array(
        'status' => $output)
)
    ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
    ->performRequest();
```